# Webpack multiple output files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am building a UI component library using React which then gets used by other my other React projects. I have React components set out in this structure:

```
components
  -- component1
       component1.js
       component1.scss
  -- component2
       component2.js
       component2.scss
  index.js
```

The index.js file just simply exports each component

```
export component1 from './component1/component1';
export component2 from './component1/component2';
```

When I build this with webpack I get the following:

```
 -- lib
    components.js
    components.css
```

containing all the code which I can then import into my app using

```
import {component1} from components
```

(components.css is imported globally)

This all works fine but I'd like to be able to build these into individual files so I can only import the components I need

```
-- lib
   -- component1
       component1.js
       component1.css
  -- component2
       component2.js
       component2.css
  index.js
```

But I still would like to be able to import in the same way:

```
import {component1} from components
```

How is this possible with webpack. Are there any plugins that would allow this or would I need to use multiple entry points etc?

Comment: Don't webpack, just use babel and sass directly (one option)

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned I'm using css modules with
import styles from './component1.scss' so I think I'll still need webpack here to extract those